# AWS Equivalent to Azure Managed Identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs

In Azure, if I were to configure a function app to post to a storage account queue, I would used managed identity for the authentication. This would remove any need to store credentials for the queue.

Does AWS have something equivalent to managed identity that could be used for a Lambda posting to SQS?

Comment: A lambda always has a role associated and that role can have policies attached that grant it the permission to send messages to a queue.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 this pointed my in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Serverless Framework

```
provider:
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - sqs:SendMessage
        - sqs:DeleteMessage
      Resource:
        - !GetAtt MyQueue.Arn
resources:
  Resources:
    MyQueue:
      Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
      Properties:
        QueueName: ${self:custom.sqs.name}
```